# Calling modals from before_filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have already asked something similar, but now it is more concrete.

I'm making login using Twitter Bootstrap modals and I want to write before save or create filter for users (I don't know what is better), that will be working like this:

```
def before_save
  if devise_error_messages
    //stay in this modal and show errors or notice
  else
   //call another modal with congratulations text
  end
end
```

How I can call `devise_error_messages` method from models or how I should do this?

Then, how can I call js from filters?